# ibm websphere how to add a specific portlet to Default.jsp

Tags: render, portlet

I find in the Default.jsp the portlets are displayed by the tag "portal-core:screenRender"; but I want to add an extra portlet to the Default.jsp, is there any way to render a specific portlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to assume you just want to a portlet to a page rather than embed a portlet in the theme itself. Adding portlet to the Default.jsp should be avoided at all costs. Not only would that be a bad place to start customizing  theme to edit the theme to embed a portlet but also just the idea of trying to embed a portlet in the theme makes me shudder a bit.

If you're just trying to add a portlet to a page, first login in as a Portal Administrator. You can then either a) navigate to the page you want to change and use the Edit Mode of the page to add a portlet from the page itself or b) go the Administration page, click "Manage Pages", find your page and edit the page there.

Comment: yes, I want to embed a portlet in the theme... I need to put a portlet stick to the top, I can use the js and css to move the portlet to top; but there will be a bug when maximize the portlet, all other portlets are disappeared. So I'm trying to embed a portlet in the theme itself. Or maybe is any other method to make the portlet always displayed.

Comment: When you maximize a portlet it is expected that other portlets on the page disappear. That's part of the JSR-286 specification. If you absolutely must use a portlet (rather than a dynamic content spot) for this theme behavior then you should contact IBM on how to do this. I can't find any documentation on how to directly embed a portlet into theme and suspect it's not supported by the product in any way.

Comment: thank you. I find a way from the flyout.jspf of the theme, it uses the iframe to display a page which only include a portlet; so I added a iframe to the Default.jsp, created a page only including the portlet I want (the page has a specific theme without navigation and foot, only the portlet content).

Comment: add something like following:
<portal-navigation:urlGeneration contentNode='XXXX' layoutNode='XXXX' newWindow='true' portletWindowState='Maximized'>
    <iframe allowTransparency="true" src="<% wpsURL.write(out); %>" />
</portal-navigation:urlGeneration>